# jquery ajax call is failing, not found

Tags: jquery, ajax

i've ran an ajax request

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../validateAcct.php',
            data: $("#createaccount").serialize(),
            success: function(response){
                var data = $.parseJSON(response);
                $("#errormessage").html(data);

            },
            error: function(data, status, error){
                alert(error);

            }






        });
```

the error it throws is not found. i keep my php files separate from js and css files just to make my localhost look a bit cleaner and easier to handle. is the problem here that i'm not using the correct method of calling a file upstairs -"../validateAcct.php" or is it that the js file needs to be in the same folder as the php?

Comment: Try specifying a full path from the root.

Comment: Calling a script page relatively (`../validateAcct.php`) is bad. Consider calling by absolute path.

Comment: The JS file can be wherever, but requests are resolved relative to the page where the JS is included. So if you're on page `accountSummary.php` and want to request `validateAcct.php` that's in the same directory, while your JS is in a `js/` subdirectory, you **don't need** the `../` part. If you use the script from multiple pages with different paths, you will need to use an absolute path in order to make the `$.ajax` call work everywhere.

Comment: You can have your files in a separate folder.. That should not be a problem. Looks like a file reference error. Check your path again..

Comment: i dunno, you guys seem like you know the answer but it works when the js file is in the same directory as the php files but not if i give it an absolute path or if i remove the relative path

Comment: ah its all good i had to remove the parsejson